# Creating a dom object on the fly with aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm pretty new on aurelia, and I don't know if this is even possible on aurelia.

I have a json with several results,

```
      "colors":[  
         {  
            "text":"#45454",
            "name":"background",
            "id":1,
            "type":"BackgroundColor"
         }
      "Description":[  
         {  
            "text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut porta sapien condimentum sagittis lobortis. Praesent molestie massa mi, eu volutpat libero condimentum in. Maecenas ultricies justo mi, eu vehicula nibh tristique vitae. Aliquam rhoncus ultrices fermentum. Duis id sapien efficitur, iaculis sapien non, laoreet felis. Aliquam dapibus commodo enim. Cras ultrices tempus justo, nec sagittis magna rutrum a.

Nullam porttitor varius lacinia. Aliquam eleifend ante tortor, non suscipit purus hendrerit eget. Ut sit amet elit mollis, venenatis tortor cursus, ornare ex. Aliquam egestas dui odio, quis malesuada ex feugiat in. Cras scelerisque, sem vitae maximus sagittis, velit orci pharetra libero, eget condimentum tortor neque in metus. Donec gravida fermentum imperdiet. Vivamus a lorem et metus maximus sollicitudin vitae eget lacus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed ultrices magna eget nunc venenatis porttitor. Nullam hendrerit ut mi et fermentum. Duis id sollicitudin tellus, a ultricies eros. Cras semper purus at convallis semper. Curabitur aliquet venenatis magna, a eleifend eros maximus eu. Duis ut iaculis velit, quis commodo urna. Quisque lacinia efficitur elit ut mollis.",
            "name":"description",
            "id":1,
            "type":"textarea"
         }
```

I would like to build from that something like this (this is pseudocode I don't know how to represent this in aurelia:

```
<input type="color" value-bind="item.name:background" />
<textarea rows="5" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="item.name:description"></textarea>
```

This means that I should create a color input if type=BackgroundColor and so on, and link it to a specific return of a json.

Comment: your json doesn't seem well-formed. However, a `value.bind="item.name"` should be enough

Comment: Hi Fabio, it's enough to bind it but it's kind of hardcoded, it doesn't know if it is a type color, text or a component textarea instead,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do can be achieved in the most simple way using the example from the docs -

```
this.items = [
  { type: 'something' },
  { type: 'somethingElse' }
]

<template repeat.for="item of items">
  <compose model.bind="item" view-model="widgets/${item.type}"></compose>
</template>
```

If your JSON isn't an array you could just push it in to the array and dynamic add and remove it from the DOM either way.

Then you can have different forms for editing each different type of whatever JSON object you have that has the appropriate form input fields.

ex something.html -

```
<input type="color" value-bind="item.name" />
<textarea rows="5" type="text" class="form-control" value.bind="item.description"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I will handle with that, will have to create a special folder with all my types

You are Patrick from aurelia team?, didn't knew you guys were taking the time to answer on here too!